# Can I know the background running process using "jobs" even i close the terminal in Linux?

Tags: linux, command, jobs

When run a process in background using &, I can see it with the command "jobs".

```
sleep 1h &
sleep 2h &
jobs
```

[image]

However, after I close the current terminal and open a new termianl, I can't find the jobs running background using the command `jobs`.

Ofcouse, I can use `ps aux | grep ...` to check the process. But I want to know can i still use `jobs` to do it. So that, it will be convient to kill the job using command like `kill %1`.

Comment: `jobs` only shows children of the current shell. Use `ps` to see other processes.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: You can't use `%1` to refer to a job, because that means the first child job of the current shell process. Once you close the terminal, there's no such relationship.

Comment: You should probably look into using `screen` or `termux` to keep the session running when you close the terminal. You can later reconnect to it.